# HX711 Ridiculous speeds

Tags: adafruit, code-review

I'm using a SparkFun HX711 board and an Adafruit AdaLogger (M0) Featherboard. I have cut the trace on the back of the HX711 to get a faster data rate (should be about 80 sps). I did this by reviewing the spec sheet and confirming with this post ([Github link for faster rates](https://github.com/olkal/HX711_ADC/issues/29)).

Before I read from the board I get startTime from micros() and immediately after I get get the scale data, I call micros() again and record the endTime. I then write this data along with the load cell data to an SD card. Then to check the time, after the experiment is over in excel I take 1/((endTime - startTime)*10^-6) to get the approximate number of samples per second.

My issue is that apparently, I'm recording at a max of around 6000 SPS but commonly around 600 SPS. Which, would be awesome if I wasn't so sure that it was a lie. I was hoping someone could take a look and see what I'm doing wrong? I used this same code on a different M0 with an unmodified HX711 and was getting around 10 SPS. The only thing different (I thought) was cutting the trace on the back of the board to enable the higher rate.

In the GitHub link above, they do mention that you can get a faster rate if you splice in a faster crystal with a cap to bridge pins 13 and 14. I have not done this, but perhaps the faster processor on the Feather might be playing some of a role in this?

VCC and VDD are both connected to 3.3V and GND is connected to the ground pin on the Feather. Pin 11 is connected to DAT and Pin 10 is connected to CLK

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SD.h>
#include "HX711.h"

#define FILE_BASE_NAME "FAST" // max six characters
#define DOUT_one 11   // Red 
#define CLK_one  10   // Orange 

const uint8_t CS_PIN = 4;
const uint8_t BASE_NAME_SIZE = sizeof(FILE_BASE_NAME) - 1;

char fileName[] = FILE_BASE_NAME "00.csv";

float calibration_factor_one = -7050; // needs to be calibrated still

File file;

long startTime=0;
long endTime =0;

String dataString = "";

double scale_one_value = 0.0;

HX711 scale_one;

void SetUpSDCard(){
  if (!SD.begin(CS_PIN)) {
    Serial.println(F("begin failed"));
    return;
    }
   while (SD.exists(fileName)) {
    if (fileName[BASE_NAME_SIZE + 1] != '9') {
      fileName[BASE_NAME_SIZE + 1]++;
    } else if (fileName[BASE_NAME_SIZE] != '9') {
      fileName[BASE_NAME_SIZE + 1] = '0';
      fileName[BASE_NAME_SIZE]++;
    } else {
      Serial.println(F("Can't create file name"));
      return;
    }
  }
   file = SD.open(fileName, FILE_WRITE);
  if (!file) {
    Serial.println(F("open failed"));
    return;
  }
  Serial.print(F("opened: "));
  Serial.println(fileName);
  }

void SetUpLoadCell(){
  Serial.println("Remove all weight from scale");  
  scale_one.begin(DOUT_one, CLK_one);
  scale_one.set_scale();
  scale_one.tare(); 

  long zero_factor_one = scale_one.read_average(); //Get a baseline reading
  Serial.print("Zero factor: "); 
  Serial.println(zero_factor_one);
  Serial.println("Load cell one initialized");
  scale_one.set_scale(calibration_factor_one); //Adjust to this calibration factor
  }

void LogData(){
  startTime= micros();
  scale_one_value = scale_one.get_units();
  endTime = micros();

  dataString = String(startTime) + "," + String(scale_one_value) + "," + String(endTime);
  file.println(dataString);
  file.flush();
  }

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  SetUpSDCard();
  Serial.println("Remove all weight from scale");
  SetUpLoadCell();
}

void loop() {
  LogData();
}
```

Then the saved data that is on the SD card is as follows, this is just the first 20 lines.

```
3383895,    0,      3384049
3401786,    0,      3401938
3411851,    0,      3412004
3421850,    -0.02,  3422004
3432012,    -0.03,  3432164
3442074,    0.01,   3442226
3452118,    0,      3452269
3462299,    0,      3462450
3472441,    0.03,   3473497
3483434,    0.03,   3485070
3495011,    0.02,   3496638
3506580,    0.01,   3508211
3518576,    0.03,   3519785
3529783,    0.02,   3531353
3541282,    0,      3542924
3552831,    0,      3554495
3564476,    0,      3566070
3575900,    0.01,   3577638
3587476,    -0.01,  3589209
3599068,    -0.03,  3600782
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not measuring how many samples you do in a second, instead you're measuring the amount of time it takes to retrieve one sample from the HX711.

You store the time, retrieve the next sample, then store the time again. Then you spend a comparative age storing that data to the SD card, during which time the HX711 is taking any number of other samples.  By the time you eventually get around to reading from the HX711 again it's already ready to give you a sample.

You need to factor in the amount of time it takes to write to the SD card to have any kind of meaningful results - that is, the total amount of time that it takes to execute a loop(), or more simply: how long since the last time your logData() function has been run.

The actual sampling time of the HX711 will probably pale into insignificance compared to all the rest of your sequential code.

Comment: oh god. lmao. Yup.. That is exactly what is going on! I feel like a moron hahaha

Answer (score 0):

To measure data sampling rate, measure elapsed time to fill an array with 10 (or better yet - 100) measurements.

```cpp
N = 100;
t0 = millis();
for (i=0; i<N; i++){
    s[i] = get_sample();
}
samplingTime = (millis()-t0)/N;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).